# How can I modify the timeout for curl with Guzzle?

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, guzzle

I am trying to upload a 2GB File to Amazon S3 with Guzzle. I am streaming the content and my code look like this:

```
$credentials = new Credentials( 'access_id', 'access_key');

        $s3 = S3Client::factory(array(
            'credentials' => $credentials
        ));;

        try {
            $s3->putObject(array(
                'Bucket' => $bucket,
                'Key'    => $obect,
                'Body'   => (strlen($body) < 1000 && file_exists($body)) ? Guzzle\Http\EntityBody::factory(fopen($body, 'r+')) : $body,
                'ACL'    => $acl,
                'ContentType' => $content_type
            ));
            return true;
        } catch (Aws\Exception\S3Exception $e) {
            error_log($e -> getMessage() . ' ' . $e -> getTraceAsString());
            return false;
        }
```

Now the error I am getting is this:

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception
>   'Guzzle\Http\Exception\CurlException' with message '[curl] 28:
>   Operation timed out after 30000 milliseconds with 0 out of -1 bytes
>   received [url]
>   https://xxxxx.s3.amazonaws.com/6e12e321-adac-42a0-a932-8f345f9dd9c6'
>   in

How can I modify the timeout for curl with Guzzle?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may set curl options by this way:

```
$s3->putObject(array(
    'Bucket' => '...',
    'Key'    => '...',
    'Body'   => '...',
    'ACL'    => '...',
    'ContentType'  => '...',
    'curl.options' => array(
       CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 10,
       CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT => 15
    )
));
```

Or try this:

```
$s3->getConfig()->set('curl.options', array(
                       CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 10,
                       CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT => 15
                     )
);
```

Comment: Just an FYI, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT is not an option. It is listed once in the example as an option but does not actually exist. It will throw a warning.

Comment: May be there are problems in *your* code? May be you want set not integer value? Because this parameter contains the documentation. At any way, this is the new question, and you may ask it in regular way at this site.